# Powershell Command to determine the Free Space of a Cluster Shared Volumes on a Remote Windows Server

Tags: windows, powershell, cluster-computing, hyper-v, diskspace

I am looking for a powershell command that will pull the free space of a Cluster Shared Volume  as it does not have a logical drive letter on a remote system. The Following is the Command I use on Logical Drives so you can see an example of the output I am Looking for. I am looking for just a numeric value of available megabytes.

```
Get-WMIObject -computer server -filter "DeviceID = 'C:'" Win32_LogicalDisk | 
              ForEach-Object {[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1MB)}
```

Thanks in advance for your Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't determine the free space of a Cluster Shared Volume (CSV) on a per-host basis. CSVs are cluster-shared resources, so you need to use [cluster tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461009.aspx) for obtaining information about them:

```psh
$cluster = 'Cluster Name'
$volume  = 'Cluster Shared Volume Name'

Import-Module failoverclusters

Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Name $volume -Cluster $cluster `
  | select -Expand SharedVolumeInfo `
  | select @{n='FreeSpace';e={($_.Partition.Size - $_.Partition.UsedSpace)/1MB}}
```